# Ubuntu 16.04: Unity refuses to launch as of this morning

Tags: 16.04, unity

I've been using my ubuntu laptop (Dell XPS13) for years and was just using it last night with no problems. This morning when I turned on my laptop and logged into my account, I found that all the unity menus and dash launchers were missing. No keyboard shortcuts worked (such as `CTRL-ALT-T` to open a terminal).

I was able to open a terminal window via the right-click menu on the desktop. I manually restarted Unity by executing `$ unity` on the command line. This resulted in a blank grey menu bar flashing momentarily across the top of the screen, but it did not fix the problem.

Unity **does** work if I login as the guest account instead of my normal account. This prompted me to try uninstalling the `fluxgui` applet from my normal account, but that did not fix the problem.

For now I've switched to `GNOME Flashback (Metacity)` instead of `Ubuntu (default)` for my desktop environment via clicking on the icon next to my login name at the login screen. This at least allows me to do anything at all with my computer.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: What about re-installing `unity desktop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by blowing away some stuff in `~/.cache`. Specifically I renamed these 4 folders in `~/.cache`:

```
apturl-gtk
com.canonical.certification.checkbox-touch
compizconfig-1
com.ubuntu.checkbox
```

Then restarted Unity with `$ unity` and saw that Unity launched correctly. I attempted to narrow down which one of the four solved the problem by restoring each folder one by one, but I was unable to recreate the original problem /shrug

My colleagues suspect that `compizconfig-1` was the culprit.